# transpose a 2d list and convert it to a 1d list

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I have a 2d list l, and

```
[l!!y!!x| x<-[0..length l-1], y<-[0..length l-1]]
```

will produce a 1d list where rows and columns are swapped.

How can I implement this without list comprehension(i.e. using map)?

Comment: also without using recursive

Comment: please add this requirement to your original question because it's a deal breaker for answers people give.

Answer (score 2):

Break down the problem into parts. To transpose a *single row*, you want to return a column where each row contains a single element. A *1 x n* matrix becomes an *n x 1* matrix:

```
{-   1 2 ... n                     1
                                   2
                                  ...
                                   n
-}

transpose [row] = map (\ x -> [x]) row
```

E.g.: `transpose [[1, 2, 3]]` = `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

`\ x -> [x]` can also be written as an operator section `(: [])` or `pure` from `Applicative`.

When you pattern-match on the outer list (input rows), you split the top row of the matrix from the remaining rows. The transpose of a matrix is the transposition of the first row prepended to the transposition of the remaining rows. You can join two matrices vertically (i.e. placing one atop the other) with `(++)` (which could be written as `(<>)` from `Semigroup`) or horizontally with `zipWith (++)` (resp. `zipWith (<>)`) (i.e. placing one beside the other). Transposed matrices are joined horizontally:

```
{-   1 2 ... n                     1   a ... p
     a b ... c                     2   b ... q
      .......                       .........
     p q ... r                     n   c ... r
-}

transpose (top : down)
  = zipWith (++) (transpose [top]) (transpose down)
```

E.g.: `transpose [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` = `[[1] ++ [3, 5], [2] ++ [4, 6]]`.

This can also be expressed as `zipWith (:) top (transpose down)` since we know we have single elements to prepend; this skips some of the redundant effort of wrapping and then immediately unwrapping the elements of the input row / output column.

Finally, the transposition of an empty matrix with *no* rows is also the empty matrix.

```
transpose [] = []
```

Putting these together:

```
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose [r] = map (: []) r
transpose (r : rs) = zipWith (:) r (transpose rs)
transpose [] = []
```

Follow-up: consider how this code responds to the edge cases where the input is non-rectangular or has an infinite number of rows or columns.

As Will Ness’s answer makes clear, this recursive function is nearly equivalent to a right fold, where the combining function is the prepending of columns by `zipWith (:)`, and the base accumulator is the empty column of indefinite height, `repeat []`, i.e. `transpose m = foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) m`, or eta-reduced, `transpose = foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])`.

However, they differ in an edge case: the fold produces an infinite list when given an empty input. That version is also equivalent to `getZipList . traverse ZipList`, based on the observation that `traverse id :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f b) -> f (t b)` is a kind of generalised transposition.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted it without explicit recursion,

`zipWith` is also a binary `map` of sorts (and in some other languages `map` actually can take any number of argument lists). Hence,

```
transposed = foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])
```

Trying it:

```
> transposed [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23,24]]
[[1,11,21],[2,12,22],[3,13,23]]
```

This can be simply composed with `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` to concatenate the transposed lists.

Answer (score 0):

We can work with *recursion* for this: each time we yield the `head`s of the lists, and then recurse on the tails, so:

```
catTranspose :: [[a]] -> [a]
catTranspose ([]:_) = []
catTranspose xs = map head xs ++ …
```

where I leave filling in `…` as an exercise. It should make a recursive call where we map each item in `xs` to its tail.

If the list is rectangular, this will work, for non-rectangular 2d lists, you will need to work with functions that are more safe, and thus will not error like `head` does on an empty list.

One can also drop the explicit recursion and work for example with [**`unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) and [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concat) that will then perform the recursion.

Comment: wouldn't `([]:_)` miss anything that follows the empty list in say `[[1,2,3],[],[4,5,6]]`?

Comment: @user1984: as specified, it will indeed only work for a rectangular list, since otherwise it will call `head` and `tail` on that empty list. One can fix that by making use of `concatMap (take 1) xs ++ ...` and work with a `safeTail :: [a] -> [a]` that for an empty list returns an empty list. I left that as an extra exercise (see last paragraph).

Comment: Thank you for explaining :D